# Are there any non-Japanese manga/anime authors or studios?

Tags: manga-production

Manga and anime famously originate from Japan, and the vast majority of the big names in manga and anime are Japanese; Hayao Miyazaki, Hideaki Anno, Hiromu Arakawa, and Masashi Kishimoto come to mind.

Outside of Japan, I can really only think of one creator who had their work become an anime/manga: The [*Deltora Quest* series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deltora_Quest_%28series%29) was adapted into an anime and manga and was created by an Australian writer, Emily Rodda.

Aside from Rodda, however, are there any* international creators, particularly from the Western world, that have successfully published manga (or anime) in Japan, *manhua* in China, or *manhwa* in Korea? Have any Western studios created and produced** anime (or rather, anime-influenced) series?

<sub>* - An exhaustive list is not necessary; a few examples from various countries and maybe some stats versus Japan, if possible.

** - Not as a result of outsourcing.</sub>

Comment: Nino Pagot, an Italian comics writer, get an anime adaptation of his Calimero in 1972 ([ANN](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=1234)). The series was broadcasted in Europe and Japan and animated by Toei.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't know of a non-Japanese studio that produces *only* anime, but the series **Oban Star Racers** was produced by a French studio, "[Sav! The World Productions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sav!_The_World_Productions)" along-side Bandai and Disney.

The Studio 4C production "[First Squad](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=10231)" has writing credits to Russian studio **Molot Entertainment Film**.

As far as mangaka, there's a lot of Korean manwha artists/writers that get published in Japanese serials. I don't think that necessarily makes them "mangaka". The series "[Blade of the Phantom Master](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blade_of_the_Phantom_Master)" by **Youn In-wan** was serialized in "Monthly Sunday Gene-X" in Japan (published by Shogakukan). **[Shin Yong-Gwan](http://www.mangaupdates.com/authors.html?id=5047)** also had his first couple of works published in "Young Champ".

As far as the western world **[Frederic Boilet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9d%C3%A9ric_Boilet)** is probably the most well known, born in France but draws comics in Japan.

Comment: The manga Freezing is a prime example of Korean artists drawing a manga in Japanese and having it animated.

Answer (score 6):

The only name that comes to my mind is the Japanese-Brazilian novelist and illustrator [**Yuu Kamiya**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Y%C5%AB_Kamiya), who works in Japan and is pretty famous now with the anime adaptation of his series [*No Game No Life*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_Game_No_Life).

Answer (score 0):

One of the creator of Dr. Stone is Korean and he was able to publish his story in Shonen Jump which later was adapted into an anime.