# If a white person/American was to make anime is it still anime?

Tags: anime-production

So let’s say an American decided to go to Japan and produce their own anime, would it still be considered an anime even if the person is not Japanese but creating it in Japan?Im not really looking for the difference between anime and cartoons, but more of what things have to be done to consider it an anime or what has to be done so that it’s not considered an anime. For example: Where it’s produced, who is producing it? etc.

Hopefully that makes sense..

Comment: I think this might help, Tony valente is a french artist who wrote a comic called Radiant, and recently it got animated by NHK enterprise (in Japan) and since then its been refered to as an anime, not a cartoon. My guess is it depends where its made and what studios/ partners are involved

Comment: Is [Are there any non-Japanese manga/anime authors or studios?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3866/are-there-any-non-japanese-manga-anime-authors-or-studios) a better duplicate?

Answer (score 1):

Yes I believe it would. I’m pretty sure (not 100%) but I think Avatar the last airbender is considered anime even though it’s an American production

Comment: Avatar is not considered to be an anime, just some people mistake it for one.

Comment: @Gorzius thank you. I’ve always heard it both ways just never knew which to believe